# Python Module names are contradicting depending on where you run the code from

Tags: python

This is my folder structure -

[image]

From **api.py** I import IncidentHandler as below -

```
import data.IncidentHandler
```

**data.IncidentHandler** works fine HOWEVER - inside of the IncidentHandler.py I have the below present:

```
import BrowserHandler
```

When I run the code from **api.py** I get this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 9, in <module>
    import data.IncidentHandler
  File "/User/**mask**/**mask**/**mask**/**mask**/tpptickethandler/src/data/IncidentHandler.py", line 1, in <module>
    import BrowserHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BrowserHandler'
```

When I run the code directly from **IncidentHandler.py** it is working as expected.

I realised that the solution was in the modular name so I have changed as follows -

```
import BrowserHandler
```

**to**

```
import data.BrowserHandler
```

This now works from **api.py** but **NOT** from **IncidentHandler.py**

**New Error from IncidentHandler.py**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IncidentHandler.py", line 1, in <module>
    import data.BrowserHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

I can see that I may be working against the typical Python principles however facing this issue was quite a unique challenge and I have not found anything on the internet thus far. Could someone please assist me with a solution and/or how to tackle this better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to organize the modules under different folders, which are **packages**. For python to recognize a folder as a package, you need to have an **__init__.py** file under it, it doesn't matter if this file is empty or not, that will let python correctly recognize the folder as a package

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

example from the official site

```
sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
              __init__.py
              wavread.py
              wavwrite.py
              aiffread.py
              aiffwrite.py
              auread.py
              auwrite.py
              ...
      effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              echo.py
              surround.py
              reverse.py
              ...
      filters/                  Subpackage for filters
              __init__.py
              equalizer.py
              vocoder.py
              karaoke.py
              ...
```

Comment: Thanks hellopeach! - I will try this. However whislt I originally had the format like this - I encountered many issues. I'll try follow this principle.